# Convert binary to list of digits Python

Tags: python, list, binary

I have the following scenario:

```
x = 0b0111
```

I would like to convert this value to:

```
y = [0, 1, 1, 1]
```

When I convert `x = 0b1001`, I can get `y = [1, 0, 0, 1]`, but when I try to do the same for `x = 0b0111`, and then convert back with `str(bin(y))` - I seem to lose the leading `0`, and get `0b111`.

Any suggestions?

Comment: `0b0111 == 0b111` so what's the problem? If you need the lists to be fixed length, then just tack on the appropriate amount of 0's to the beginning.

Answer (score 10):

Once you get that string `0b111`, it's straightforward to split out the digits that you're interested in. For each character of everything after the `0b` in the string, convert it to an integer.

```
[int(d) for d in str(bin(x))[2:]]
```

Comment: The object returned by _bin(x)_ is of type _<class 'str'>_, I think we don't need to explicitly convert it to str() again and this should work: **[int(d) for d in bin(x)[2:]]**

Answer (score 5):

For what it's worth, a pure arithmetic solution appears to be marginally faster:

```
import timeit

def bits1(n):
    b = []
    while n:
        b = [n & 1] + b
        n >>= 1
    return b or [0]

timeit.timeit(lambda: bits1(12345678))
[out] 7.717339038848877

def bits2(n):
    return [int(x) for x in bin(n)[2:]]


timeit.timeit(lambda: bits2(12345678))
[out] 10.297518014907837
```

2019 update: In python 3.7.3 the second version is slightly faster.

Comment: For python 3 you should move the `list` from inside the `map` to outside the `map`. You can also win some performance by using `b.append(n&1)` rather than `b = [n & 1] + b`. Unfortunately(?) in my case the `bits2` option is 10 times faster than the pure version.

Comment: @ThomasAhle: thanks, the `bits2` version edited. In py3 it's slightly faster, but not as much as  10x.

Answer (score 3):

First convert the number to binary and then to string:

```
str(bin(7))
'0b111' #note the 0b in front of the binary number
```

Next, remove the `0b` from the string

```
str(bin(7))[2:]
'111'
```

Finally we use list comprehension to create a list of ints from the string, which has *roughly* the following form:

```
[expr for i in iterable]
[int(i) for i in str(bin(x))[2:]]
```

Answer (score 3):

An expression like `map(int, list(bin((1<<8)+x))[-4:])` will give you the low 4 bits of a number, as a list.  (*Edit: A cleaner form is* `map(int,bin(x)[2:].zfill(4))` *; see below*.)  If you know how many bits you wish to show, replace the 4 (in `[-4:]`) with that number; and make the 8 (in `(1<<8)`) a larger number if necessary.  For example:

```
>>> x=0b0111
>>> map(int,list(bin((1<<8)+x))[-4:])
[0, 1, 1, 1]
>>> x=37; map(int,list(bin((1<<8)+x))[-7:])
[0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1]
>>> [int(d) for d in bin((1<<8)+x)[-7:]]
[0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1]
```

The last example above shows an alternative to using map and list.  The following examples show a slightly cleaner form for obtaining leading zeroes.  In these forms, substitute the desired minimum number of bits in place of 8.

```
>>> x=37; [int(d) for d in bin(x)[2:].zfill(8)]
[0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1]
>>> x=37; map(int,bin(x)[2:].zfill(8))
[0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1]
>>> x=37; map(int,bin(x)[2:].zfill(5))
[1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1]
>>> x=37; map(lambda k:(x>>-k)&1, range(-7,1))
[0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1]
```

Answer (score 3):

Updated for f-String:

```
x = 0b0111
y = [int(i) for i in f'{x:04b}']
```

y = [0, 1, 1, 1]

or:

```
x = 0b0111 # binary representation of int 7
n_bits = 4 # desired bits' len
y = [int(i) for i in f'{x:0{n_bits}b}']
```

Will populate a list of minimum len n-bits filling the list with leading 0's

Answer (score 2):

If the length of bits is fixed to `4`, there are two solutions:

```
[int(i) for i in '{0:04b}'.format(0b0111)]
```

or with NumPy,

```
import numpy as np
[int(i) for i in np.binary_repr(0b0111, 4)]
```

Answer (score 0):

check this simple way to do it... for this particular scenario

```
In [41]: x=0b0111

In [42]: l = [0,0,0,0]

In [43]: counter = -1

In [44]: for i in str(bin(x))[2:]:
   ....:     l[counter] = i
   ....:     counter = counter -1
   ....:

In [45]: l
Out[45]: [0, '1', '1', '1']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
c=[]
for i in bin(7)[2:]: 
        c.append(int(i)) #turning string "111", to 111
if len(c)==3:
    c.insert(0,0)
print(c)

# binary digit 7 produces '0b111' by this slicing[2:], result get '111'
```

so if element in list c is 3, 0 is inserted first.

Comment: Kindly Post some explanation of the answer as well.

Answer (score 0):

Not very pythonian but:

```
byte = 0b00011001
arr = []
for i in range(7, -1, -1):
    arr.append((byte & 1<<i)>>i)
print(arr)

[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1]
```

this uses bitmasking to "extract" each bit and append to an array.

Answer (score 0):

Given a number `value` and number of bits to represent it in `width`:

```
string = format(value, '0{}b'.format(width))
binary_list = [0 if c == '0' else 1 for c in string]
```

This is about one third faster than `binary_list = [int(c) for c in string]`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple on-liner with no string parsing needed:

```
[x >> bin_idx & 1 for bin_idx in reversed(range(x.bit_length()))]
```

I believe it's a bit faster than other answers posted here.