# Convert integer to pytorch tensor of binary bits

Tags: pytorch

Given an number and an encoding length, how can I convert the number to its binary representation as a tensor?

Eg, given the number `6` and width `8`, how can I obtain the tensor:

```
(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0)
```

Comment: Related: [Convert binary to list of digits Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13081090/5353461)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```py
def binary(x, bits):
    mask = 2**torch.arange(bits).to(x.device, x.dtype)
    return x.unsqueeze(-1).bitwise_and(mask).ne(0).byte()
```

If you wanna reverse the order of bits, use it with `torch.arange(bits-1,-1,-1)` instead.

Comment: this is so elegant

Answer (score 9):

[Tiana's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55918468/convert-integer-to-pytorch-tensor-of-binary-bits) was a good one. BTW, to convert Tiana's 2-base result back to 10-base numbers, one can do like this:

```py
import torch
import numpy as np


def dec2bin(x, bits):
    # mask = 2 ** torch.arange(bits).to(x.device, x.dtype)
    mask = 2 ** torch.arange(bits - 1, -1, -1).to(x.device, x.dtype)
    return x.unsqueeze(-1).bitwise_and(mask).ne(0).float()


def bin2dec(b, bits):
    mask = 2 ** torch.arange(bits - 1, -1, -1).to(b.device, b.dtype)
    return torch.sum(mask * b, -1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    NUM_BITS = 7
    d = torch.randint(0, 16, (3, 6))
    b = dec2bin(d, NUM_BITS)
    # print(d)
    # print(b)
    # print(b.shape)
    # print("num of total bits: {}".format(np.prod(b.shape)))

    d_rec = bin2dec(b, NUM_BITS)

    # print(d_rec)
    print(abs(d - d_rec).max())  # should be 0.
```

Comment: Why `.float()` and not `.byte()` as per the referenced answer?

Comment: Yes, in general cases you can use `.byte()` here. I used `.float()` because I needed to pass the results to a third-party evaluating program, which required the bits in `float` format. Anyway, all the numbers were still either `0` or `1`.

Comment: Good answer, but actually nothing to deal with decimal... Input tensor 'x' is already in binary, the function puts its bits into separate tensors rather than convert its base!

Comment: For large integers (64 bits), this gives "RuntimeError: Overflow when unpacking long". Can anyone suggest a solution?

Answer (score 0):

If the input is unsigned bytes and the output width is 8 bits:

```
>>> binary = np.unpackbits(np.array([0xaa, 0xf0], dtype=np.uint8))
>>> print(torch.tensor(binary))
tensor([1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0], dtype=torch.uint8)
```

Note that [`unpackbits()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unpackbits.html#numpy-unpackbits) **only** operates with `np.uint8`.

Answer (score -1):

```
def decimal_to_binary_tensor(value, width=0):
    string = format(value, '0{}b'.format(width))
    binary = [0 if c == '0' else 1 for c in string]
    return torch.tensor(binary, dtype=torch.uint8)
```

Examples:

```
>>> print(decimal_to_binary_tensor(6, width=8))
tensor([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0], dtype=torch.uint8)

>>> print(decimal_to_binary_tensor(6))
tensor([1, 1, 0], dtype=torch.uint8)
```